# Expand Rows and Add Columns in Data Frame Based On Another Data Frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, mapply

## Overview

Each row in `team.df` consists of one [NBA team](https://twitter.com/NBA?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor). Each data frame in `list.of.all.stars` contains multiple rows based on the number of [all star players](http://www.nba.com/allstar/2018/roster#/) associated with each NBA team.

Using the [`apply()`](http://faculty.nps.edu/sebuttre/home/R/apply.html) family of functions, how can I expand the rows in `team.df` to grow by the number of all star players by each team **and** combine the columns from the `list.of.all.stars` to the final output?

I'm totally open to non-`apply()` methods as well, just wanted to give an example that I'm hoping to avoid writing for loops.

Below is my desired output:

```
#   Team_Name Team_Location         Player Captain
# 1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH   LeBron James    TRUE
# 2 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH     Kevin Love   FALSE
# 3  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Stephen Curry    TRUE
# 4  Warriors   Oakland, CA   Kevin Durant   FALSE
# 5  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Klay Thompson   FALSE
# 6  Warriors   Oakland, CA Draymond Green   FALSE
```

## Reproducible Example

```
# create data frame 
# about team information
team.df <-
  data.frame(
    Team_Name       = c( "Cavaliers", "Warriors" )
    , Team_Location = c( "Cleveland, OH", "Oakland, CA")
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# create list about
# all stars on each team
list.of.all.stars <-
  list( 
    data.frame(
      Player = c( "LeBron James", "Kevin Love" )
      , Captain = c( TRUE, FALSE )
      , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    , data.frame( 
      Player = c( "Stephen Curry", "Kevin Durant"
                  , "Klay Thompson", "Draymond Green"
      )
      , Captain = c( TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE )
      , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
```

## Non apply() family method

```
# cbind each data frame within the list.of.all.stars
# to its corresponding row in team.df
team.and.all.stars.list.of.df <-
  list(
    cbind(
      df[ 1, ]
      , list.of.all.stars[[1]]
    )
    ,   cbind(
      df[ 2, ]
      , list.of.all.stars[[2]]
    )
  )
# Warning messages:
#   1: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
#   row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
# 2: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
#   row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

# collapse each list
# into data frame
final.df <-
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      what = "rbind"
      , args = team.and.all.stars.list.of.df
    )
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
# view final output
final.df
# Team_Name Team_Location         Player Captain
# 1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH   LeBron James    TRUE
# 2 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH     Kevin Love   FALSE
# 3  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Stephen Curry    TRUE
# 4  Warriors   Oakland, CA   Kevin Durant   FALSE
# 5  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Klay Thompson   FALSE
# 6  Warriors   Oakland, CA Draymond Green   FALSE

# end of script #
```

## Failed mapply() attempt

```
# Hoping to Apply A Function
# using a data frame and
# a list of data frames
mapply.method <-
  mapply(
    FUN = function( x, y )
      cbind.data.frame(
        x
        , y
        , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    , team.df
    , list.of.all.stars
  )

# view results
mapply.method
#         Team_Name   Team_Location
# x       Character,2 Character,4  
# Player  Character,2 Character,4  
# Captain Logical,2   Logical,4 

# end of script #
```

Comment: do you *have* to use an `apply` function? And do you have control on the structure of the list of data.frames?

Comment: @SymbolixAU I would like to but I'm open to learning new methods! The order of objects in `list.of.all.stars` is associated with the order of the row in `team.df`. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the OP's approach of using 'team.df' as input in the `Map/mapply`  'team.df' is a `data.frame` which is a `list` of columns.  So, the basic input is a column of `vector`.  It loops through the `vector` or column instead of the whole dataset or the rows (based on the desired output).  To prevent that, if we wrap with `list`, it is a single unit, which recycles to each of the `list` elements of the 'list.of.all.stars'

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, list(team.df), list.of.all.stars))
```

---

Based on the expected output, each row of 'team.df' should have the corresponding `list` element of 'list.of.all.stars'.  In that case, `split` the 'team.df' by the rows and do the `cbind`

```
res <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind,  split(team.df, seq_len(nrow(team.df))), list.of.all.stars))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#   Team_Name Team_Location         Player Captain
#1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH   LeBron James    TRUE
#2 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH     Kevin Love   FALSE
#3  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Stephen Curry    TRUE
#4  Warriors   Oakland, CA   Kevin Durant   FALSE
#5  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Klay Thompson   FALSE
#6  Warriors   Oakland, CA Draymond Green   FALSE
```

---

We can also do this in `tidyverse`.  After grouping by all the columns in 'team.df', `nest` it to create a base list of 'data' (which will be of length 2), assign 'data' to 'list.of.all.stars' in `mutate` and `unnest` the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
team.df %>% 
      group_by_all() %>%
      nest %>% 
      mutate(data = list.of.all.stars) %>% 
      unnest
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Team_Name Team_Location Player         Captain
#  <chr>     <chr>         <chr>          <lgl>  
# 1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH LeBron James   T      
# 2 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH Kevin Love     F      
# 3 Warriors  Oakland, CA   Stephen Curry  T      
# 4 Warriors  Oakland, CA   Kevin Durant   F      
# 5 Warriors  Oakland, CA   Klay Thompson  F      
# 6 Warriors  Oakland, CA   Draymond Green F
```

Comment: I think your first method gives an incorrect result. For example, Stephen Curry is in a row for Cleveland (given the edit to the question and desired output)

Comment: @SymbolixAU  Yes, I updated the description.  It is just to specify how it loops.

Comment: yep I see that now.

Comment: @akrun thank you for the explanation and helpful examples with base [tag:r] and the [tag:tidyverse]. I appreciate you helping me understand `mapply` better, too!

Answer (score 3):

Given the edit to the question and the desired output, I would do it purely using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

## combine the list of all stars into one data.table
## creating an 'id' column 
dt_players <- rbindlist(list.of.all.stars, idcol = T)

## we can keep/use the row names as the order of the data 
## is consistent with the list elements 
dt_teams <- as.data.table(team.df, keep.rownames = T)
dt_teams[, rn := as.integer(rn)]

## use a join to combine the data to get the desired result. 
dt_teams[
  dt_players
  , on = c(rn = ".id")
]

#    rn Team_Name Team_Location         Player Captain
# 1:  1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH   LeBron James    TRUE
# 2:  1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH     Kevin Love   FALSE
# 3:  2  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Stephen Curry    TRUE
# 4:  2  Warriors   Oakland, CA   Kevin Durant   FALSE
# 5:  2  Warriors   Oakland, CA  Klay Thompson   FALSE
# 6:  2  Warriors   Oakland, CA Draymond Green   FALSE
```

---

#### Old answers

This method uses `data.table` to do the actual work, but I've given you an `sapply` method for grabbing the number of rows by which to expand the `team.df` data frame.

It also assumes the order of teams in `team.df` is consistent with the order of players inside `list.of.all.starts` (i.e., the rows of the `data.frame` correspond to the list elements )

```
library(data.table)

## grab the rows of each data.frame
reps <- sapply(list.of.all.stars, nrow)

## replace the rows of the data.frame
setDT(team.df)[rep(1:.N, reps), ]

#    Team_Name Team_Location
# 1: Cavaliers Cleveland, OH
# 2: Cavaliers Cleveland, OH
# 3:  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 4:  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 5:  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 6:  Warriors   Oakland, CA
```

---

If you didn't want to use `data.table`, the same approach can be applied to a `data.frame`

```
team.df[rep(row.names(team.df), reps), ]
#     Team_Name Team_Location
# 1   Cavaliers Cleveland, OH
# 1.1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH
# 2    Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 2.1  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 2.2  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 2.3  Warriors   Oakland, CA
```

---

Or using similar concepts, but all inside an `lapply`

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(list.of.all.stars), function(x) {
  df <- team.df[x, ]
  df[rep(row.names(df), nrow(list.of.all.stars[[x]])), ]
})

do.call(rbind, lst)
#     Team_Name Team_Location
# 1   Cavaliers Cleveland, OH
# 1.1 Cavaliers Cleveland, OH
# 2    Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 2.1  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 2.2  Warriors   Oakland, CA
# 2.3  Warriors   Oakland, CA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @SymbolixAU! I've got to start learning [tag:data.table]. You are the second person in less than a week to take take 10+ lines of code and condense into a one-liner. I appreciate your help and for adding the examples of how to expand a data.frame based on the previous version of the question.

Comment: @aspiringurbandatascientist it's a very useful package - I use it daily in my work. On smaller data sets you won't see much benefit between it and the `tidyverse` - it will come down to personal preference on which syntax you like. However, on 10+millions of rows it will start to pay-off.